# Are apache syncope or WSO2 IS suitable choices to handle access control?

Tags: rest, spring-security, wso2-identity-server, access-control, apache-syncope

I have some rest APIs developed using Spring. Depending on the perissions of different users, the access control process should be applied to these services. For example, based on a number of rules (that can be changed), only some of the services will be accessible to a user. Also, some services are applicable only for certain different ranges of parameter values for different users. Are apache syncope or WSO2 IS suitable choices to handle access control as described above? Is there any other alternatives for this?